# Why error "cannot init a class object" occur when I execute my objective-C program?

Tags: objective-c

I just begin to learn objective-C. My first problem is I can't run the below source code.

Here is my source code:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Volume : NSObject
-(id)init;
@end

@implementation Volume
-(id)init 
{
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}
@end

int main(void){
  id o;
  o = [Volume init];
}
```

Here is my error output:

```
$cc 96.m -framework Foundation
$./a.out
2014-09-18 10:10:40.116 a.out[759:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[Volume<0x1069ca0f8> init]: cannot init a class object.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9019525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff951f4e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90198490 +[NSObject(NSObject) dealloc] + 0
    3   a.out                               0x00000001069c9f46 main + 38
    4   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff93bab5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is my Environment:

```
$cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `alloc/init`**

`[Volume init]` is an invalid message. There is no class method for `init`.

However, `[Volume alloc]` creates a Volume object, which you can then call `init` on.

`[[Volume alloc] init]` is valid because once the object is `alloc`ated, it can be `init`ialized.

`alloc` reserves the spot in memory for the object to exist. `init` actually takes that memory and sets up an object that you can use.

**Using `new`**

If you want to be able to call a single method instead of `[[Volume alloc] init]`, you can call `[Volume new]`. While that is valid, it is not used often.

**Using a class object-initializer**

You can also implement a class method to create a new volume.

```
+ (instancetype) volume{
    return [[Volume alloc]init];
}
```

Then, you can use `Volume *vol = [Volume volume];`

Comment: Ah, I got it there is no class method as you said. So I need to first create Volume object. Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Class initialisation in Objective C takes place in two stages: first you allocate memory for the instance, and then you initialise that instance.

So you need to do:

```
o = [[Volume alloc] init];
```

What you're currently doing is attempting to call `init` as a class method on `Volume`, when it's an instance method (called on the new instance returned by `alloc`).